# yii2 creating custom action in controller Page not Found

Tags: php, yii

```
namespace app\Controllers;

use Yii;
use app\models\Projects;
use app\models\ProjectSearch;
use app\models\Employees;
use yii\web\Controller;
use yii\web\NotFoundHttpException;
use yii\filters\VerbFilter;

/**
 * ProjectController implements the CRUD actions for Projects model.
 */
class ProjectController extends Controller
{
    public function behaviors()
    {
        return [
            'verbs' => [
                'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
                'actions' => [
                    'delete' => ['post'],

                ],
            ],
        ];
    }

    public function actionGetAvailableEmployees($id=null){
        $available_employees = Projects::getAvailableEmployees($id);
        return json_encode($available_employees);
    }


}
```

My `/config/web.php` is this:

```
 'urlManager'=>array(
        'enablePrettyUrl'=>'true',
        'showScriptName'=>false,
        'rules'=>array(
            '' => '/',
            '<action:(index|page|contact|login|logout|NotAllowed)>'=>'site/<action>',
            '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
        ),
    ),
```

When i try to access the url with this `http://mysite.dev/project/get-available-employees/1` I am getting a page not found error, what seems to be the problem here? I am new to Yii2.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using the `basic` or `advanced` application template?
What do you get using this url: `http://mysite.dev/index.php?r=project/get-available-employees&id=1`?

Comment: Add the rules in this order,
'<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
'<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
'<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>'